# Get buildings polygons points from mapbox with fetch API only

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I try to get the buildings geometry coordinates polygons from features, but i cant seem to find a way for this to work without the javascript method queryRenderedFeatures or SourceFeatures.
This question [Getting building information from mapbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325687/getting-building-information-from-mapbox-api) uses the javascript method, but i want something to work with a link, that i can fetch a json from.

I have managed to come close with something like this: 
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/tilequery/27.598505,47.162098.json?radius=30&layers=road,poi_label,building,geometry&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE.
But this has a major flaw:
It only returns geometry as a point:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":235028771,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[27.598497434198464,47.16209573500234],"type":"building"...}}
```

You can observe that it returns a point even though it is a building.
Is there a way to do this?
The queryRenderedFeatures method DOES return a polygon. Somehow the information reaches the Map object that i query but how can i fetch through an api that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible. Mapbox doesn't provide complete polygon datasets. At best, there are ways of retrieving polygons from vector tilesets (such as [query-remote-tiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-remote-tiles), which does something similar to TileQuery). But these will only retrieve the part of the polygon within a given vector tile, which may not be what you want. (queryRenderedFeatures has the same issue).

Comment: Thanks. So far queryRenderedTiles returned - as far as i know - closed polygons. Or something was wrong but i didnt notice. I am just curious how Mapbox GL can actually draw the buildings... But i understand now that this functionality is not present. Do you happen to know a service that would help me instead? With mapbox is as close as i could reach so far...